# async / await issue for my homework project: Stock Price Checker

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

If I enter the stock "goog" in [my app](https://chalk-typhoon.glitch.me) the log is :

```
responseStock = 
stockPrice = 1193.9900
updateStockPrice was a success
[ { stock: 'GOOG', price: '1193.9900', likes: 0 } ]
```

I've read many, many article on async / await (and Promises), including on stackoverflow.com, and asked this question on the freeCodeCamp forum, but did not get a response or have been able to figure it out.  I've tried so many variations of my code and have not been able to solve the async issue.  Where I am at is putting await / async on all functions but it does not work.

```
app.route('/api/stock-prices')
    .get(function (req, res){
    var stock1 = req.query.stock1.toUpperCase();
    var stock2; //if stock2 compare stock prices
    if (req.query.stock2) { stock2 = req.query.stock2.toUpperCase();}
    var like = req.query.like ? 1 : 0;
    //console.log("like " + like)
    var ip = like ? req.ip : null;
    //console.log("ip is " + ip);
    var stockPrice;
    var responseStock = [];

    var sendResponse = async (response) => {
      if (response.lenght > 1) { //user entered 2 stocks to compare
        var likes0 = response[0].likes - response[1].likes; //compare relative likes
        var likes1 = response[1].likes - response[0].likes;
        await res.json({"stockData": [{"stock": response[0].stock, "price": response[0].price, "rel_likes": likes0},
                               {"stock": response[1].stock, "price": response[1].price, "rel_likes": likes1}]});
      } else {
        console.log("responseStock = " + response);
        await res.json({"stockData": response});

      };
    };

    var addNewStock = async (stock) => {
      var newStock = await new Stock({stock: stock, price: stockPrice, likes: like});
      console.log(newStock);
      newStock.save( (err, doc) => {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        else if (!doc) { console.log("addNewStock failed")} 
        else {
          console.log("addNewStock was a success"); 
          responseStock.push({"stock": doc.stock, "price": doc.price, "likes": doc.likes});
          console.log(responseStock);
        }
      });
    };

    var updateStockPriceAndLikes = async (stock) => {
      await Stock.findOneAndUpdate({stock: stock}, {price: stockPrice, $inc: {likes: like}, $push: {ip: ip}},
                             {new: true}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        else if (!doc) { console.log("updateStockPriceAndLikes failed"); }
        else { 
          console.log("updateStockPriceAndLikes was a success"); 
          responseStock.push({"stock": doc.stock, "price": doc.price, "likes": doc.likes});
          console.log(responseStock);
        }
      })
    };

    var updateStockPrice = async (stock) => {
      console.log("stockPrice = " + stockPrice)
      await Stock.findOneAndUpdate({stock: stock}, {price: stockPrice},
                             {new: true}, async function(err, doc) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        else if (!doc) { console.log("updateStockPrice failed"); }
        else { 
          console.log("updateStockPrice was a success");
          responseStock.push({"stock": doc.stock, "price": doc.price, "likes": doc.likes});
          console.log(responseStock);
        }
      })
    };

    var handleStock = async (stock) => {
      if (stock) {
       if (ip) {   // like is checked
       await Stock.findOne({stock: stock}, async function(err, doc) {
          if (err) { console.log(err); }
          else if (!doc) { 
           await  addNewStock(stock); //not in db, add new
          } else if (doc.ip.indexOf(ip) < 0) {  //ip not found
            await updateStockPriceAndLikes(stock);   //and push ip to db
          } else {
            await updateStockPrice(stock);
          }
        })
       } else if (!ip) {   //like is not checked
        await Stock.findOne({stock: stock}, async function(err, doc) {
          if (err) { console.log(err); }
          else if (!doc) {
            await addNewStock(stock);
          } else {
            await updateStockPrice(stock);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  };

    var getStockPrice = async (stock) => {  
      var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol="
                + stock + "&apikey=" + process.env.ALPHA_API_KEY;
        await request(url, {json: true}, async function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
          else if (!body["Global Quote"]["05. price"]) {
            await res.send("please enter a valid stock");
          }
        else {
          //console.log("stockPrice = " + body["Global Quote"]["05. price"]); //correctly logs stock price
          stockPrice = body["Global Quote"]["05. price"];
          await handleStock(stock);
        } 
      })
    };

    var begin = async () => {  
      await getStockPrice(stock1);
      if (stock2) {
        await getStockPrice(stock2);
      }  
      await sendResponse(responseStock);
    };

    begin();
    /*responseStock = [ { stock: 'GOOG', price: '1250.4100', likes: 0 },
  { stock: 'MSFT', price: '141.3400', likes: 0 } ]*/


    });
```

I expect the log to be

```
stockPrice = 1193.9900
updateStockPrice was a success
[ { stock: 'GOOG', price: '1193.9900', likes: 0 } ]
responseStock = [{ stock: 'GOOG', price: '1193.9900', likes: 0 }]
```

So, it seems, I have an async issue that I can't figure out.

Comment: In ```sendResponse``` you haven't ```return```.

Comment: Read this carefully.  Using `await` on a function that does NOT return a promise does nothing useful.  It doesn't wait for an asynchronous operation to complete if that function does not return a promise that is linked to the operation.  You are doing this wrong in a lot of places with `request()` with `res.json()` with `res.send()` and with all your database operations, etc....  Go back to your reference material and read more about how `await` and `async` work.

Comment: Cont'd... This needs to be significantly rewritten.  Personally, I would "promisify" all the asynchronous operations I need to use (perhaps with `util.promisify()` and learn and use the promise interface to my database rather than the plain callback interface.  The, you could legitimately use `async` and `await` to serialize asynchronous operations.

Comment: Also, we don't generally like to write homework solutions for you.  We'd rather teach you how to write your own code.  So, you should probably ask a more specific question about one specific part of the code or one specific technical question.

Comment: My question/problem is I'm trying to get a stock price from an API, save that to ````var responseStock = [];```` and then send a response with the data.  But the response is sent before the data is received from the API.  My entire structure may be wrong.  I'm looking for tips on how to change the structure or a tip on how my current structure could work.

Comment: I didn't ask anyone to write me a solution.  I asked my question in the homework section.  I thought that was what this section is for - helping people that are trying to learn.

Comment: @eoaja could you simplify the code to show what needs to work? It's hard to read 122 lines of code and figure out what's wrong with it. Please strip it to the absolute minimum that can work without async, then add async to the point where it stops working.

Comment: @kevinadi thanks for taking a look.  I just figured this out minutes ago.  Like @jfriend00 said "Using await on a function that does NOT return a promise does nothing useful."  So I changed all my functions that I needed to ````await```` on so that they returned a promise.  Everything seems to work as expected now.  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @eoaja glad to hear it's solved. Could you please post an answer on how you got it fixed to close the loop and help people with similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jfriend00 mention in the comments, `await` will not work on a function that does not return a promise.  So, the functions that I need to use `await` on I had to change to return a promise.

So, for example this did not work:

```
var getStockPrice = (stock) => {  
  //request data from API
};

var begin = async () => {  
  await getStockPrice(stock1);
  if (stock2) { await getStockPrice(stock2); }  
  sendResponse(responseStock);
};

begin();
```

But this does work:

```
var getStockPrice = (stock) => {  
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { 
      //Request data from API
      resolve();
    })   
};

var begin = async () => {  
  await getStockPrice(stock1);
  if (stock2) { await getStockPrice(stock2); }  
  sendResponse(responseStock);
};

begin();
```